# How to auto fill HTMl input and trigger onChange so that submit button works

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a script to automate one task, it suppose to be very simple, however for some reason when I make the button clicked by JS script the input is cleared instead of submitting the data.

the input element and button are as follow:

```js
document.querySelector('input[placeholder="Add Id"]').value = "123";
document.querySelector('Button[data-testid="modalSubmitBtn"]').click()
```

```html
<input placeholder="Add Id" id="formField2-1667914655837-4613" autocomplete="on" type="text" aria-invalid="true" value="">


<button data-testid="modalSubmitBtn" type="submit" data-awsui-focus-visible="true"><span class="sub">Submit</span></button>
```

What I noticed is, when I type in the input field manually via keyboard I see this attribute is added to the button

```
data-focus-visible="true"
```

The event tab next to the button element shows for click:

```
function cn() {}
```

And for onClick it shows:

```
function(e) {
  if (D && L) return e.preventDefault();
  D && bt(e) && gt(u, null, e);
  var t = e.altKey,
    n = e.button,
    r = e.ctrlKey,
    i = e.metaKey,
    a = e.shiftKey;
  gt(l, {
    altKey: t,
    button: n,
    ctrlKey: r,
    metaKey: i,
    shiftKey: a
  }, e)
}
```

and for the input element, it showsfor onChange:

```
function(e) {
  return Z(e.target.value)
}
```

I tried to use something similar to the following but didn't help:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("linkid");
if (typeof elem.onclick == "function") {
    elem.onclick.apply(elem);
}
```

I will appreciate any hints for what am I missing to make it work.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

HTML `<form>` element will do the work for you. Wrap your input and button with `<form>`, define the form `method` (get/post) and the `action` (url). Then just hit the button and the form will be submitted for you. No JS is needed.

```js
document.querySelector('input[placeholder="Add Id"]').value = "123";
//document.querySelector('Button[data-testid="modalSubmitBtn"]').click()
```

```html
<form method="get" action="https://www.google.com/search">
  <input placeholder="Add Id" id="q" name="q" autocomplete="on" type="text" aria-invalid="true" value="">


  <button data-testid="modalSubmitBtn" type="submit" data-awsui-focus-visible="true"><span class="sub">Submit</span></button>
  </form>
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint, however this is not an option for me. This is a website that is already built, I'm only trying to automate one task we usually do once the webpage is loaded, we need every time to add a specific id, so I wanted to create a script that fills the input automatically for us and clicks the submit so we can continue.
I have no control of the web page where I need my script to work, the page is not created by me.